# Reactive Extensions Parallel processing based on specific number

Tags: .net, system.reactive, throttling, reactive-programming

I'm new to Reactive Extensions. I have objects collection and call a method for each object and method returns Boolean. Instead of looping through each by using for each loop and calling the method, is there a way in **reactive extensions** to call concurrently(fork and join) the method for a given number of objects(ex 5 at a time) and after first one done, 6th one should call method and it should continue until all the objects are done.

I appreciate your response.

Comment: Have you looked at http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc3?

Comment: thanks for your comment. rxwiki's example throttle is based on time. I want by number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
IObservable<bool> someBoolAsyncMethod(SomeObject o)

someCollection.ToObservable()
    .Select(x => Observable.Defer(() => 
        someBoolAsyncMethod(x).Select(y => new { Item = x, Result = y})))
    .Merge(5)
    .ToList()
    .Subscribe(newListOfBools);
```