# Rx extensions Parallel.ForEach throttling

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm following the answer to this question: [Rx extensions: Where is Parallel.ForEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558835/rx-extensions-where-is-parallel-foreach) in order to run a number of operations in parallel using Rx.

The problem I'm running into is that it seems to be allocating a new thread for *every* request, whereas using `Parallel.ForEach` did considerably fewer.

The processes I'm running in parallel are quite memory intensive, so if I'm trying to process hundreds of items at once the answer provided to the linked question quickly sees me running out of memory.

Is there a way I can modify that answer to throttle the number of items being done at any given time?

I've taken a look at the `Window` and `Buffer` operations, my code looks like this:

```
return inputs.Select(i => new AccountViewModel(i))
    .ToObservable()
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .ToList()
    .Do(l =>
    {
        using (Accounts.SuppressChangeNotifications())
        {
            Accounts.AddRange(l);
        }
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .SelectMany(acc => Observable.StartAsync(async () =>
    {
        var res = await acc.ProcessAsync(config, m, outputPath);
        processed++;
        var prog = ((double) processed/inputs.Count())*100.0;
        OverallProgress.Message.OnNext(string.Format("Processing Accounts ({0:000}%)", prog));
        OverallProgress.Progress.OnNext(prog);
        return res;
    }))
    .All(x => x);
```

Ideally I want to be able to batch it up into chunks of account view models, that I then call the `ProcessAsync` method on, and only once all of that batch are done move on.

Ideally I'd like it so that if even only one of the batch finished, it moved on, but only ever kept the same batch size.

So if I've got a batch of 5 and 1 finishes, I'd like another to start, but only one until more space is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, Paul Betts has answered a similar question that solves my problem:

The question: [Reactive Extensions Parallel processing based on specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178683/reactive-extensions-parallel-processing-based-on-specific-number)

Has some information on using `Observable.Defer` and then merging into batches, using that I've modified my previous code like so:

```
return inputs.Select(i => new AccountViewModel(i))
    .ToObservable()
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .ToList()
    .Do(l =>
    {
        using (Accounts.SuppressChangeNotifications())
        {
            Accounts.AddRange(l);
        }
    })
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .Select(x => Observable.DeferAsync(async _ =>
    {
        var res = await x.ProcessAsync(config, m, outputPath);
        processed++;
        var prog = ((double) processed/inputs.Count())*100.0;
        OverallProgress.Message.OnNext(string.Format("Processing Accounts ({0:000}%)", prog));
        OverallProgress.Progress.OnNext(prog);
        return Observable.Return(res);
    }))
    .Merge(5)
    .All(x => x);
```

And sure enough, I get the rolling completion behaviour (e.g. if 1/5 finish then just one starts).

Clearly I've got a few more fundamentals to grasp, but this is brilliant!

Comment: Fyi you can use `FromAsync` instead of `DeferAsync` which lets your async lambda more naturally just return its result without needing to wrap it with `Return`.

Comment: Also note that your code to track and report progress has some multithreaded race conditions and potentially violates some Rx concurrency rules. I suggest moving all of the progress tracking code into a `Do` clause right after the `Merge` clause. That will eliminate the races.

Comment: @Brandon wouldn't moving that to a Do after the Merge just mean that progress reporting only takes place after every batch? I want to report progress after every item.

Comment: No `Merge` lets items through one by one as they complete. Note that `merge(5)` is *not* batching operations. It is just ensuring that only 5 are ever running simultaneously. As soon as a single operation finishes, it lets another queued operation start.  If you want true batching you would need to use something like `Buffer` or `Window`